# Getting float array from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have float array inside C++ function.

C++ function

```
void bleplugin_GetGolfResult(float* result)
{
    float *array = new float[20];
    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
      array[i]= 25;
    result = array;
    //DEBUG PRINTING1
    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
       cout << result[i] << endl;//Here is correct
    return;
}
```

Inside C#

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static unsafe extern void bleplugin_GetGolfResult (float* result);

public static unsafe float[] result = new float[20];

public unsafe static void GetGolfREsult(){
    fixed (float* ptr_result = result) //or equivalently "... = &f2[0]" address of f2[0]
    {           
        bleplugin_GetGolfResult( ptr_result );
        //DEBUG PRINTING2
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            Debug.Log("result data " + ptr_result[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

I called `GetGolfREsult()` from another function to get result.

`//DEBUG PRINTING1` has correct output.

But `//DEBUG PRINTING2` produced 0 only.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you assigning values to the array in your C# method?

Comment: Never use the assignment operator on the parameter

Comment: `result` is passed by value. Therefore it is pointless assigning to it. Your problems begin way before there is any C# code. Your C++ function is currently of no use whatsoever. You are getting ahead of yourself. Make sure your C++ code works before you try to call it from C++. And there's no need for unsafe code here.

Comment: If you can add a hint about the array size (and fix your C++ code as David pointed out), you can use the solution provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221566/7841).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your C++ code:

```
float *array = new float[20];
```

creates a new array, which you operate on in C++. Then control returns to C#, who has it's own array and that's still unchanged. Why don't you write to the array you got?

Comment: I think the actual flaw in OP's thinking is that `result = array;` would assign (copy?) this array back to C#

Comment: Because I like to copy array data to result. What you meant to write the array i got. I don't get it.

Comment: Actually I used  float *array as a simple example. That array is already there for some reason and I can't use parameter result to create array at C++ function.

Comment: @batuman `result = array;` does not modify the passed in array (it wouldn't do that if you were working exclusively in C++ either), it just redirects the local pointer to the array. You need to write directly into the passed in array (by `result[i] = 25;` instead of `array[i] = 25;`)

Answer (score 4):

As UnholySheep and nvoigt already stated,

```
result = array;
```

overrides the address of the passed pointer, making you lose the reference to the calling function.

Directly writing to your parameter should solve this.

```
result[i] = 25;
```

Further you dont actually have to use pointers in c#.
You can actually do the following:

Declare your Import like this:

```
private static extern void bleplugin_GetGolfResult (float arr[]);
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
float arr = new float[20];
bleplugin_GetGolfResult(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the assignment operator on the parameter result which prevents the data from being transferred to the C# array on return.

Using the following C++ example:

```
void z(int * x)
{
  x = new int(4);
}

int main()
{
  int * x = new int(-2);
  z(x);
  cout<<*x<<endl;
}
```

The output for this is -2 not 4 because you use the assignment operator on the parameter.

Comment: What should I do for that?

Comment: @batuman could pass an array to the function with a length of 20 then you would just change the value of each spot in the array